# Unity meta & svn files

Tags: c#, svn, unity-game-engine, tortoisesvn, metadata

Is there any way to remove from Unity's `Project` panel the `svn` files that are generated when a repository conflict is resolved?

The `meta` files that are generated when you activate svn-compatible scripting, thankfully don't show up in the `Project` panel, but I wonder about `svn` files...

There were a few conflicts when I committed my latest Unity C# code to our SVN, so I ended up with some extra versions of each of those conflicting scripts, which cluttered my Unity `Project` panel.

So, I resolved them using the `TortoiseSVN`'s `mine resolution` (as opposed to `theirs`) in the hope of getting rid of those files, but now I have one more of each (the mine files!).

How do I get back to a normal state of the Unity `Project` panel without removing any `svn` related files?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to the TortoiseSVN documentation

> You can either launch an external merge tool / conflict editor with TortoiseSVN → Edit Conflicts or you can use any text editor to resolve the conflict manually. You should decide what the code should look like, do the necessary changes and save the file. Using a merge tool such as TortoiseMerge or one of the other popular tools is generally the easier option as they generally present the files involved in a 3-pane view and you don't have to worry about the conflict markers. If you do use a text editor then you should search for lines starting with the string <<<<<<<.
>
> Afterwards execute the command TortoiseSVN → Resolved and commit your modifications to the repository. Please note that the Resolve command does not really resolve the conflict. **It just removes the filename.ext.mine and filename.ext.r* files, to allow you to commit your changes.**

http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-conflicts.html

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the .mine and .theirs files, they are not included in the SVN data.